# Interval expressions in gawk to awk

Tags: regex, awk, expression, intervals

I hope this is an easy fix

I originally wrote a clean and easy script that utilized gawk, I used this first and foremost because when I was solving the original issue was what I found. I now need to adapt it to only use awk.

sample file.fasta:

```
>gene1

>gene235
ATGCTTAGATTTACAATTCAGAAATTCCTGGTCTATTAACCCTCCTTCACTTTTCACTTTTCCCTAACCCTTCAAAATTTTATATCCAATCTTCTCACCCTCTACAATAATACATTTATTATCCTCTTACTTCAAAATTTTT

>gene335
ATGCTCCTTCTTAATCTAAACCTTCAAAATTTTCCCCCTCACATTTATCCATTATCACCTTCATTTCGGAATCCTTAACTAAATACAATCATCAACCATCTTTTAACATAACTTCTTCAAAATTTTACCAACTTACTATTGCTTCAAAATTTTTCAT

>gene406
ATGTACCACACACCCCCATCTTCCATTTTCCCTTTATTCTCCTCACCTCTACAATCCCCTTAATTCCTCTTCAAAATTTTTGGAGCCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTTCAAAATTTTTCACCATACCAATAATATCCCTCTTCAAAATTTTCCACACTCACCAAC


gawk '/[ACTG]{21,}GG/{print a; print}{a=$0}' file.fasta >"species_precrispr".fasta
```

what I know works is awk is the following:

```
awk '/[ACTG]GG/{print a; print}{a=$0}' file.fasta >"species_precrispr".fasta
```

the culprit therefore is the interval expression of {21,}

What I want it to do is search is for it to match each line that contains at least 21 nucleotides left of my "GG" match.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

Thanks for all the help:
There are various solutions that worked. To reply to some of the comments a more basic example of the initial output and the desired effect achieved...

Prior to awk command:
cat file1.fasta

```
>gene1
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTGG 
>gene2
ATGGGTGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTG
>gene3
ATGTCAAAATTTTTCATTTCAAT
>gene4
ATCCTTTTTTTTGGGTCAAAATTAAA
>gene5
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTTTTTAAAATTTTTGG
```

Following codes all produced the same desired output:

original code

```
gawk '/[ACTG]{21,}GG/{print a; print}{a=$0}' file1.fasta
```

slight modification that adds interval function to original awk version >3.x.x

```
awk --re-interval'/[ACTG]{21,}GG/{print a; print}{a=$0}' file1.fasta
```

Allows for modification of val and correct output , untested but should work with lower versions of awk

```
awk -v usr_count="21" '/gene/{id=$0;next} match($0,/.*GG/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2);if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>= usr_count){print id ORS $0};id=""}' file1.fasta

awk --re-interval '/^>/ && seq { if (match(seq,"[ACTG]{21,}GG")) print ">" name ORS seq ORS} /^>/{name=$0; seq=""; next} {seq = seq $0 } END { if (match(seq,"[ACTG]{21,}GG")) print ">" name ORS seq ORS }' file1.fasta
```

Desired output: only grab genes names and sequences of sequences that have 21 nucleotides prior to matching GG

```
>gene1
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTGG 
>gene5
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTTTTTAAAATTTTTGG
```

Lastly just to show the discarded lines

```
>gene2
ATG-GG-TGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTG # only 3 nt prior to any GG combo 
>gene3
ATGTCAAAATTTTTCATTTCAAT # No GG match found 
>gene4
ATCCTTTTTTTTGGGTCAAAATTAAA # only 14 nt prior to any GG combo
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Replace `[ACTG]{21,}` with `[ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG][ACTG]+`? ;)

Comment: you might be interested in using [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk)

Comment: Add the flag `--re-interval` Only from newer versions of GNU awk have this as default.

Comment: This is somewhat implementation specific, but for instance FreeBSD `awk` documents: *"     The awk utility is compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 ("POSIX.1")
     specification, except awk does not support {n,m} pattern matching."*

Comment: When providing a [mcve] for a matching question it's important to a) provide input with lines that do and lines that are similar to but don't match your criteria, and b) show the expected output given your sample input. Otherwise we don't have anything to test against to see if a potential solution works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP comment need to print gene ids too then try following.

```
awk '
/gene/{
  id=$0
  next
}
match($0,/.*GG/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2)
  if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>=21){
    print id ORS $0
  }
  id=""
}
' Input_file
```

OR one-liner form of above solution as per OP's request:

```
awk '/gene/{id=$0;next} match($0,/.*GG/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2);if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>=21){print id ORS $0};id=""}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
match($0,/.*GG/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2)
  if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>=21){
    print
  }
}
' Input_file
```

OR more generic approach where created a variable in which user could mention value which user is looking to match should be present before GG.

```
awk -v usr_count="21" '
match($0,/.*GG/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2)
  if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>=usr_count){
    print
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/.*GG/){                    ##Using Match function to match everything till GG in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2)    ##Storing sub-string of current line from RSTART till RLENGTH-2 into variable val here.
  if(gsub(/[ACTG]/,"&",val)>=21){    ##Checking condition if global substitution of ACTG(with same value) is greater or equal to 21 then do following.
    print                            ##Printing current line then.
  }
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk accepts interval expressions in regular expressions from version 3.0 onwards. However, only from version 4.0, interval expression became defaultly enabled. If you have awk 3.x.x, you have to use the flag `--re-interval` to enable them.

```
awk --re-interval '/a{3,6}/{print}' file
```

---

There is an issue that often people overlook with FASTA files and using awk. When you have multi-line sequences, it is possible that your *match* is covering multiple lines. To this end you need to combine your sequences first.

The easiest way to process FASTA files with awk, is to build up a variable called `name` and a variable called `seq`. Every time you read a full sequence, you can process it. Remark that, for the best way of processing, the sequence, should be stored as a continues string, and not contain any newlines or white-spaces due. A generic awk for processing fasta, looks like this:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { **process_sequence_here** }
     /^>/{name=$0; seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { **process_sequence_here** }' file.fasta
```

In the presented case, your sequence processing looks like:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { if (match(seq,"[ACTG]{21,}GG")) print ">" name ORS seq ORS}
     /^>/{name=$0; seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { if (match(seq,"[ACTG]{21,}GG")) print ">" name ORS seq ORS }' file.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is:

```
awk 'match($0,/[ACTG]+GG/) && RLENGTH>22{print a; print} {a=$0}' file
```

but this is probably all you need given the sample input you provided:

```
awk 'match($0,/.*GG/) && RLENGTH>22{print a; print} {a=$0}' file
```

They'll both work in any awk.

Using your updated sample input:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*GG/) && RLENGTH>22{print a; print} {a=$0}' file
>gene1
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTGG
>gene5
ATGCCTTAACTTTCAATAACTTTTTAAAATTTTTGG
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I added what your comment required; I'll keep that in mind moving forward. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to show it working given your new sample input/output.